# How to actually uninstall node-gyp

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

node-gyp is giving me a lot of hassle while trying to uninstall... I have tried using both **npm remove node-gyp** and **npm -g uninstall node-gyp** but even after both say they are successful I still get gyp errors when trying to run npm install.

Comment: Try install using ```yarn``` package manager. Or if you want only ```npm```, you need to install build tools : ```sudo apt-get install build-essential``` . ```yarn``` can simply install like this: ```sudo npm i -g yarn```

Comment: Some modules with native code need gyp to build. Maybe your problem isn’t node-gyp but something it needs.